# Ajax call always returning as Undefined and not reaching code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I understand that this question has been asked quite a lot, but I am interested as in why my method is constantly returning 'Undefined' and the ajax is never actually calling the code behind method. I copied this code from another response and was supposed to work. I attempted many different ajax calls and none will reach the back end. (Also, I apologize in advanced if the formatting is off.)

' VB

```
Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
End Sub

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetCurrentTime(ByVal name As String) As String
    Return "Hello " & name & Environment.NewLine & "The Current Time is: " &
             DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Function
End Class
```

'JavaScript and Markup

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="TargetWeightEditor.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
        data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        Your Name :
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time"
            onclick = "ShowCurrentTime()" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I changed "json" to "text" and it did not change the issue.

Comment: So you are saying it is JSON being returned, but you are returning a string.

Comment: Have you tried putting the target URL of the AJAX into the browser to see what the result is there? I have a feeling you have misconfigured your web service in the page, but am unfamiliar with VB.NETs implementation to confirm without research of my own.

Comment: @epascarello could you please explain? I am obviously a beginner and have looked into converting strings to json in vb but can not find an explicit answer.

Comment: Been 10+ years since I touched VB.net, so I can not help

Answer (score 1):

This might not solve it if there's an underlying problem but try these things first. Some are just to clean up the code.

Remove `type ="text/javascript"` from all the script tags. You don't need it in HTML 5.

In the `ajax` call, remove `dataType: "json",`. You don't need anything there. Let it return the default type.

On the `asp:TextBox`, add `ClientIDMode="Static"`. Then you won't need `$("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")`. After changing that, try this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ name: $("#txtUserName").val() }),

// you might want/need to set the user name before the
// ajax call: 
var un = $("#txtUserName").val();
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify({ name: un }),
    ...
```

Move your script to below the HTML, just before the closing body tag.

Update the code in your original post too after making changes. HTH.